# Am I saving data to my sqllite database correctly?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

First I have my sql statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_BADGES =
        "create table if not exists badges (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name VARCHAR, description VARCHAR, image_url VARCHAR, club_id VARCHAR, created_at VARCHAR);";
```

Then I make sure this is created:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try {
            Log.i("execSQL", "Creating badges");
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_BADGES);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Next I have my saving method in which i specify the values when i call the method. The Log,i shows a valid string:

```
//---updates a badge record---
public boolean updateBadgesRecord(long rowId, String id, String name, String description, String image_url, String club_id, String created_at) 
{

    Log.i("image_url in updateBadgesRecord", image_url);
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    if(id != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_ID, id);
    }
    if(name != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_NAME, name);
    }
    if(description != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, description);
    }
    if(image_url != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, image_url);
    }
    if(club_id != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, club_id);
    }
    if(created_at != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT, created_at);
    }

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Before calling these methods I am opening the database with:

```
db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

I THINK it is saving. This is how I am trying to get the data:

```
public Cursor getBadgeRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db  = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_BADGES_ID, KEY_BADGES_NAME, KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT}, 
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Here is where I am calling the method, **However**, the prinln returns null:

```
public void activateBadgeList(){
    for(int i = 0; i < badgeButtons.length; i++){
        if(true){
        badgeButtons[i].setActivated(true);
        badgeButtons[i].setAlpha(1.0f);

        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getBadgeRecord(i);
        String image_url = null;
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
               while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                  image_url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image_url"));
                  // do what ever you want here
                  c.moveToNext();
               }
            }
            c.close();
        if(image_url != null){
        Log.i("image url", image_url);
        } else {
        Log.e("image url", "image url is null");    
        }
        badgeButtons[i] = UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(badgeButtons[i], image_url);
        db.close();
        }
    }
```

So I must be doing something wrong... But what is it?

Comment: Avoid the where condition and fetch all data Select * from .... Then try to iterate the cursor....  It could be the rowID you are looking for is not found..!! Just a first thought..

Comment: try to replace Varchar with text, may be work. also use Log to trace for problem.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesnt seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is: db.update(...) only updates existing rows. do db.insert(...) before hand.